# Best way to decode unknown unicoding encoding in Python 2.5

Tags: python, html, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

Have I got that all the right way round? Anyway, I am parsing a lot of html, but I don't always know what encoding it's meant to be (a surprising number lie about it). The code below easily shows what I've been doing so far, but I'm sure there's a better way. Your suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
import logging
import codecs
from utils.error import Error

class UnicodingError(Error):
    pass

# these encodings should be in most likely order to save time
encodings = [ "ascii", "utf_8", "big5", "big5hkscs", "cp037", "cp424", "cp437", "cp500", "cp737", "cp775", "cp850", "cp852", "cp855", 
    "cp856", "cp857", "cp860", "cp861", "cp862", "cp863", "cp864", "cp865", "cp866", "cp869", "cp874", "cp875", "cp932", "cp949", 
    "cp950", "cp1006", "cp1026", "cp1140", "cp1250", "cp1251", "cp1252", "cp1253", "cp1254", "cp1255", "cp1256", "cp1257", "cp1258", 
    "euc_jp", "euc_jis_2004", "euc_jisx0213", "euc_kr", "gb2312", "gbk", "gb18030", "hz", "iso2022_jp", "iso2022_jp_1", "iso2022_jp_2", 
    "iso2022_jp_2004", "iso2022_jp_3", "iso2022_jp_ext", "iso2022_kr", "latin_1", "iso8859_2", "iso8859_3", "iso8859_4", "iso8859_5", 
    "iso8859_6", "iso8859_7", "iso8859_8", "iso8859_9", "iso8859_10", "iso8859_13", "iso8859_14", "iso8859_15", "johab", "koi8_r", "koi8_u", 
    "mac_cyrillic", "mac_greek", "mac_iceland", "mac_latin2", "mac_roman", "mac_turkish", "ptcp154", "shift_jis", "shift_jis_2004", 
    "shift_jisx0213", "utf_32", "utf_32_be", "utf_32_le", "utf_16", "utf_16_be", "utf_16_le", "utf_7", "utf_8_sig" ]

def unicode(string):
    '''make unicode'''
    for enc in self.encodings:
        try:
            logging.debug("unicoder is trying " + enc + " encoding")
            utf8 = unicode(string, enc)
            logging.info("unicoder is using " + enc + " encoding")
            return utf8
        except UnicodingError:
            if enc == self.encodings[-1]:
                raise UnicodingError("still don't recognise encoding after trying do guess.")
```

Comment: Automatic detection knows *absolutely nothing* about your text, but if you know at least the language the text is in there are only very few options. That's why encoding detection basically means trying to guess the language based on the frequency of letters.

Comment: Erm, unicode() returns Unicode and not UTF-8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two general purpose libraries for detecting unknown encodings:

- chardet, part of [Universal Feed Parser](http://feedparser.org)
- UnicodeDammit, part of [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

chardet is supposed to be a port of the [way that firefox does it](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html)

You can use the following regex to detect utf8 from byte strings:

```
import re

utf8_detector = re.compile(r"""^(?:
     [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]            # ASCII
   | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
   |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
   | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
   |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
   |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
   | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
   |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
  )*$""", re.X)
```

In practice if you're dealing with English I've found the following works 99.9% of the time:

1. if it passes the above regex, it's ascii or utf8
2. if it contains any bytes from 0x80-0x9f but not 0xa4, it's Windows-1252
3. if it contains 0xa4, assume it's latin-15
4. otherwise assume it's latin-1

Comment: I coded this up and put it here http://pastebin.com/f76609aec

Comment: There's a problem the code you pasted: `^(?:\xA4)*$` will match if the string is *entirely* `\xA4` and no other characters. You just need `re.compile(r'\xA4')` and `re.compile(r'[\x80-\xBF]')` for the two other regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I've tackled the same problem and found that there's no way to determine a content's encoding type without metadata about the content. That's why I ended up with the same approach you're trying here.

My only additional advice to what you've done is, rather than ordering the list of possible encoding in most-likely order, you should order it by specificity. I've found that certain character sets are subsets of others, and so if you check `utf_8` as your second choice, you'll miss ever finding the subsets of `utf_8` (I think one of the Korean character sets uses the same number space as utf).

Comment: Indeed. `ascii` is a subset of `utf-8` and will also correctly decode as `utf-8`, so you can leave `ascii` out. 8-bit encodings such as `latin-1` will decode to _something_ in all cases, so put one of these last.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Python, you might try [`UnicodeDammit`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit). It is part of [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) that you also may find useful.

Like the name suggests, `UnicodeDammit` will try to do whatever it takes to get proper unicode out of the crap you may find in the world.

Comment: Tried that early on, but it failed quite a bit.

Comment: Really! What were the problems? It may be easier to get that working than to roll your own.

Comment: "The crap you may find in the world"?