# Decode string with hex characters in python 2

Tags: python, utf-8, hex, python-2.x

I have a hex string and i want to convert it utf8 to insert mysql. (my database is utf8)

```
hex_string = 'kitap ara\xfet\xfdrmas\xfd'
...
result = 'kitap araştırması'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you define hex_string in your source or is it from an external source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Python 2.6,

```
>>> print('kitap ara\xfet\xfdrmas\xfd'.decode('iso-8859-9'))
kitap araştırması
>>> 'kitap ara\xfet\xfdrmas\xfd'.decode('iso-8859-9').encode('utf-8')
'kitap ara\xc5\x9ft\xc4\xb1rmas\xc4\xb1'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working. But is there any way to do that without knowing source encoding?

Comment: @user: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715772/best-way-to-decode-unknown-unicoding-encoding-in-python-2-5.

Answer (score 6):

Try(Python 3.x):

```
import codecs
codecs.decode("707974686f6e2d666f72756d2e696f", "hex").decode('utf-8')
```

From [here](https://python-forum.io/Thread-convert-hex-encoded-string-to-ASCII).

Answer (score 1):

[String literals](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html) explains how to use UTF8 strings in Python source.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hex_string.decode("cp1254").encode("utf-8")
```

(`cp1254` or `iso-8859-9` are the Turkish codepages, the former being the usual name on Windows platforms, but in Python, both work equally well)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decode it from the encoded bytes you have. That appears to be ISO-8859-9 (latin-5), or, if you are using Windows, probably [code page 1254](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254), which is based on latin-5.

```
>>> 'kitap ara\xfet\xfdrmas\xfd'.decode('cp1254')
u'kitap ara\u015ft\u0131rmas\u0131' # u'kitap araştırması'
```

If you *are* using Windows, then depending on where you are getting those bytes, it *might* be more appropriate to decode them as `mbcs`, which translates to ‘whichever code page the local system is using’. If the string is just sitting in a `.py` file, you would be better off just writing `u'kitap araştırması'` in the source and setting a `-*- coding` declaration to  direct Python to decode it. See [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

As to how to encode unicode strings to UTF-8 for the database, well, if you want to you can do it manually:

```
>>> u'kitap ara\u015ft\u0131rmas\u0131'.encode('utf-8')
'kitap ara\xc5\x9ft\xc4\xb1rmas\xc4\xb1'
```

but a good data access layer is likely to do that automatically for you, if you've got the `COLLATION` of the tables the data is going into right.