# Bash equivalent to Python's string literal for utf string conversion

Tags: python, bash, utf-8

I'm writing a bash script that needs to parse html that includes special characters such as `@!'ó`. Currently I have the entire script running and it ignores or trips on these queries because they're returned from the server as decimal unicode like this: `&#39;`. I've figured out how to parse and convert to hexadecimal and load these into python to convert them back to their symbols and I am wondering if bash can do this final conversion natively. Simple example in python:

```
print ur"\u0032" ur"\u0033" ur"\u0040"
```

prints out

```
23@
```

Can I achieve the same result in Bash? I've looked into iconv but I don't think it can do what I want, or more probably I just don't know how.

Here's some relevant information:

[Python String Literals](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html)

[Hex to UTF conversion in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045876/convert-hex-to-utf-in-python)

And here are some examples of expected input-output.

> `Ludwig van Beethoven - 5th Symphony and 6th Symphony &#39;&#39;Pastoral&#39;&#39; - Boston Symphony Orchestra - Charles Munch`
>
> `Ludwig van Beethoven - 5th Symphony and 6th Symphony ''Pastoral'' - Boston Symphony Orchestra - Charles Munch`
>
> `&#1040;&#1083;&#1080;&#1089;&#1040; (Alisa) - &#1052;&#1099; &#1074;&#1084;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;&#1077;. &#1061;&#1061; &#1083;&#1077;&#1090; (My vmeste XX let)`
>
> `АлисА (Alisa) - Мы вместе. ХХ лет (My vmeste XX let)`

Comment: you can't call python or perl from that bash script to process the string?

Comment: nearly done so:

`echo '&#1040;&#1083;&#1080;&#1089;&#1040; (Alisa)' | perl -pe 's/&#(\d+);(?{$x=sprintf("%04x", int($1))})/\N{U+$x}/g'`

unfortunately, there's some problem with the `$x` conversion, so that the unicode chars are wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `printf` builtin in Bash doesn't support Unicode codes, but the external `printf` (at least on my GNU-based system) does:

```
$ /usr/bin/printf "\u0410\u043b\u0438\u0441\u0410"
АлисА
```

or this, which selects `printf` from your path in case it's not in `/usr/bin`:

```
$ $(type -P printf) "\u0410\u043b\u0438\u0441\u0410"
АлисА
```

or

```
$ env printf "\u0410\u043b\u0438\u0441\u0410"
АлисА
```

Comment: Dennis Williamson: it's much better than sending a string to some python/perl/whatever one-liner

Comment: Thanks! I thought it shouldn't be as difficult as I thought but now that I'm looking into python it looks fairly attractive to learn.

Comment: Not to mention someone has already made modules to encode and decode html.

Answer (score 1):

possible solution, e.g.:

```
$ function conv() { echo $* | python -c 'import re, sys; print re.sub(r"&#(\d+);", lambda x: unichr(int(x.group(1))), sys.stdin.read()).rstrip()' ; }
$ conv '&#1040;&#1083;&#1080;&#1089;&#1040; (Alisa)' 
АлисА (Alisa)
```

Comment: if `UnicodeEncodeError` occurs, add `reload(sys); sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8");` after `import re, sys;`

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new to programming, and I wonder whether calling python or other languages causes a considerable use of system resources?

Comment: @teratomata yes, it is slow. launching of e.g. perl is considerably fater than python. but i would be still slower than if you could do it in bash (echo) directly